# How, in Ionic app, to return from open.window() to Azure B2C authentication workflow back to specific page?

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, azure-ad-b2c

Preamble:

I am attempting to authenticate user through Azure AD B2C.  I am doing this by constructing the URL and then presenting this via the window.open.  It navigates to the authentication flow, and on success (assuming it was because I can see the token in the returned URL in browser) but it routes back to localhost:8100/null.  How can I have it navigate back to specific page?

GOAL:

Authenticate hybrid (PWA) on mobile (Android and iOS) and Web

SETUP:

1. Azure AD B2C
2. Ionic
3. APIs via .NET Core 2.x (irrelevant)

URL navigated either with InAppBrowser (native Android) or window.open() on web:

```
https://mycorp.b2clogin.com/mycorp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
p=B2C_1_Login&client_id=(my_client_id)
&nonce=defaultNonce
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

Native:

Using InAppBrowser with on("exit") to extract token_id is working

Web:

1. window.open I am unable to get a callback to get token_id
2. _self allows for navigating to azure b2c auth workflow inside same window, but returns user to my localhost:8100/null which is not a valid page

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this ? I'm using Ionic 4 + capacitor, and can't successfully authenticate with AD B2C on Android and iOS

Comment: This project got stalled, but from what I recall the process of authenticating with the Azure B2C requires you have configuration correct, and perhaps also be managing individual config for each of the types of clients, like Android, iPhone, Browser and then use the ionic framework methods to build logic that composes the correct URL to call authentication for the correct target client.  Sorry.. it is complicated by nature of it being security across multiple mobile devices.